# How to mock a method call on an object created inside the method being tested

Tags: java, junit, mockito, powermockito

I have a class with a rest end point like:

```
@Path("/myPath/myFunction")
public class MyClass {
    @Get
    @Path("someSpecificFunction")
    public Response getSomeData(@QueryParam("myVar") String myVar) {
        MyObject myObject = new MyObject();
        JsonObject response = myObject.getJson(myVar);
        return Response.ok(response.toString()).build();
    }
}
```

I want to write a unit test for `getSomeData` and want to mock `myObject.getJson` call.

What is the best way to do this?

I want to avoid `@PrepareForTest` on `MyClass` if possible.

I tried converting creation of `MyObject` instance to a static method like:

```
protected static MyObject createMyObject() {
    return new MyObject();
}
```

But `PowerMockito` requires `@PrepareForTest` even for mocking or static methods.

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `PowerMocktio` using `whenNew()`

, Steps

1. PrepareForTest `MyClass`
2. Use `whenNew` which means when a new object is instantiated, the use this mocked one

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(MyClass.class)
public class ExampleClassTest {

    private MyClass myClass;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        myClass = new MyClass();
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldDoSomething() {
        MyObject mocked = mock(MyObject.class);
        PowerMockito.whenNew(String.class).withNoArguments().thenReturn(mocked);

        assertEquals("mocked", myClass.getString());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to change the design of the class and having the test injecting `MyObject`

Something like

```
public MyClass {
   MyObject myObject = new MyObject()

   public method(){
      ...
   }

}


MyClassTest {

    @Test
    public test() {
       MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
       myClass.myObject = mock(MyObject.class);
       //test code
    }
}
```

This simplify testability and can work with any framework, also if you have a DI framework will help introducing it.